# What does SessionFactory do internally when crud operations get called in given application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was understanding about spring + hibernate + java integration. So i got clear picture on below given points:

1. Spring uses LocalSessionFactoryBean class to create SessionFactory which is hibernate class.
2. Application context load the definition for datasource, hibernate properties etc.
3. we can inject SessionFactory class in spring dao classes.
   My question is on crud operation invocation, like

   sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().get(--, -)

How it works internally in terms of using datasource or any other spring/hibernate related resources ?

Comment: You should read http://www.amazon.in/Hibernate-Action-Patrick-Peak/dp/193239415X?tag=googinhydr18418-21 for a complete understanding of how hibernate works.

Comment: i would surely do that but for now could you please help me in understanding this like what sessionfactory get method does everytime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain at hight level what happen, for more detail you can check the source code.

First of all in your line of code 2 methods are called:

- `getCurrrentSession()` on session factory
- `get(--,--)` in the returned session

In the first method hibernate use the `CurrentSessionContext` to retreive the acual session. The  `CurrentSessionContext` implementation substantially looks if there is an open session with an open transaction related to your thread and your session facotry and return it; to make it simpler it loooks if you are doing something on this DB in this thread and allow You to continue. If the `CurrentSessionContext` doesn't find a session a new one is create. (Note there are many implementation of `CurrentSessionContext` by default JPA one is used)

After retreive the session the second method is executed. In the second method referring to the dialect and other objects a native sql query is generated. In your specific case the sql is sent over the session to the database, the step looks like:

- if the session is not binded to a connection, ask for a db connection from the pool
- send the sql over the connection and retreive a resultset
- get the resultset and tranlaste it to the entity object wich will be returned

if you are doing a dml operation (update, insert ...) the sql is tored on the session and it will be sent after flushing the session(you can use the `flush()` method it, otherwise just commit and wait hibernate do ti for you). Important note, committing the Transaction means that the code will be execute on the DB. After commit hibernate, with his own timing, will open a transaction over the db connection (**important hibernate transacion is not a db transaction**) will execute all the generate sql statement and will commit the DB transaction. This is the flush operation, remember yo don't exactally know when the flush happen since you don't force it manually with the `flush()` method.

hope this hepl
r.

Comment: Thank you so much for great explanation. Does it have dependency on Spring DriverManagerDataSource for each subsequent operation(like read, update, delete ?) to get the connection and generate native sql.

Comment: The DriverManagerDataSource is used to retreive the connection and also (as far as I know) it is not reccomended in production environnement. The native sql is generated using the dialect,

Comment: Do we have any other way of getting connection except DriverManagerDataSource if it is not recommended to use in production ?

Comment: datasource, connection pool....you can have a look here to see an example http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring